# programmatically determine if an evaluation of a function is being assigned?

Tags: python

I would like to do this:

```
def foo():
    if <a magical condition>:
        return x
    else:
        poof()

# or...
def foo():
    x = <a magical object>
    return x

def poof():
    print 'poof!'

bar = foo()  # bar points to <a magical object> but poof() is not called

foo() # prints 'poof!'
```

I guess it comes down to what the circumstanses are when the returned object's `__del__` method is called.  But maybe there is a better way.  Like if the function itself knew it's returned value was being assigned.  I guess I'm worried about relying on the timing of the garbage collection.  Also I don't like that global `at_end_of_program` flag.

My solution:

```
class Magic:
    def __del__(s):
        poof()

def foo():
    x = Magic()
    return x

def poof():
    if not at_end_of_program:
        print 'poof!'

bar = foo()  # No poof.

foo() # prints 'poof!'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty confused by your question, but I think what you are trying to do is run a function when a value is reassigned.

Instead of doing tricky things with a `__del__()` method function, I suggest you just put your value into a class instance, and then overload `__setattr__()`.  You could also overload `__delattr__()` to make sure you catch `del(object.x)` for your value `x`.

The very purpose of `__setattr__()` is to give you a hook to catch when something assigns to a member of your class.  And you won't need any strange end_of_program flag.  At the end of your program, just get rid of your overloaded function for `__delattr__()` so it doesn't get called for end-of-program cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

A function can't tell what its return value is used for.  Your solution will print poof if you re-assign to `bar` for example.

What's the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I would have to avoid re-assigning `bar` until after setting the `at_end_of_program` flag to True.  I am trying to sometimes pass, sometimes close a COM object that gets created by a function, depending on whether it is "requested" or not by the call of the function.  The COM object does not get closed when garbage collected.